# Choices in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

My Models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    # book types and placed
    BIOGRAFIA = 1
    FANTASTYKA = 2
    HISTORYCZNY = 3
    HORROR = 4
    POEZJA = 5
    PRZYGODA = 6
    ROMANS = 7
    DRAMAT = 8
    BRAK = 0
    B00K_CHOICES = (
        (BIOGRAFIA, 'Biografia'),
        (FANTASTYKA, 'Fantasy/Sci-Fi'),
        (HISTORYCZNY, 'Historyczny'),
        (HORROR, 'Horror'),
        (POEZJA, 'Poezja'),
        (PRZYGODA, 'Przygoda'),
        (ROMANS, 'Romans'),
        (DRAMAT, 'Dramat'),
        (BRAK, 'Brak informacji'),
    )
    tytul = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    autor = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    opis = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    gatunek = models.IntegerField(choices=B00K_CHOICES, default=BRAK)
    cena = models.DecimalField(max_digits=400, decimal_places=2)
    rok_wydania = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    liczba_stron = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    zdjecie = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=True, upload_to='zdjecia_ksiazek')
    przecena = models.BooleanField()



    def __str__(self):
        return self.tytul
```

My View:

```
def Gatunek(request, gatunek_id):
    ksiazki = Book.objects.filter(gatunek=gatunek_id)
    return render(request, 'ksiazki.html', {'ksiazki': ksiazki})
```

I don't think my view is too good, I don't know if it should also be {{gatunek. gatunek}}

My template HTML:

```
                     {% for ksiazki in ksiazki  %}
                    <div class="card" style="width: 500px">
                        <div class="card-body">
                                <img src="/media/{{ksiazki.zdjecie}}">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <h2>{{ksiazki}}</h2>

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <a href="{% url 'Edytuj_ksiazke' ksiazki.id %}"><i class="fas fa-2x fa-edit"></i></a>
                                    <a href="{% url 'Usun_ksiazke' ksiazki.id %}"><i class="fas fa-2x fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                                <p>{{ ksiazki.gatunek }} </p>
                                <p>{{ ksiazki.opis }}</p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                        {% endfor %}
```

It seems to me that I have a problem in Django when I am looking for a field that has a selection parameter. I don't get the field names, but instead I get the number for a strange reason.
Please Help

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain the textual representation of a choice, you can use the [**`get_fieldname_display()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display), so here, `.get_gatenuk_display()`. In your template, you render this with:

```
{{ ksiazki.get_gatunek_display }}
```

You should *not* include parenthesis. Django's template language does not allow this, but will automatically call callables.

Answer (score 0):

I have one more question how to make my template (html) in navbar (boostrap) show all your choices = B00K_CHOICES